# ajax post works with chrome, firefox but not internet explorer

Tags: ajax, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have the following ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "Plan.aspx/SaveData", 
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO), 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.d == "YES") {
            check = response.responseText;
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        check = "Error: " + response.responseText;
        return false;
    }
});
```

This code works with Firefox and chrome, but not Internet Explorer.  No errors occur on either end.  The strange thing is the code works in the Visual Studio IDE (VS 2013), but not when deployed on IIS 7.5.  I've searched all over for an answer with no luck.

Anyone here have any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
Edited to add success code, which never executes because the ajax call is never executed on IE, but does on Firefox and Chrome!

Comment: I don't see a success callback? also, can you do a console.log on your error callback and check the console if that is being called? SideNote : Ajax (async:false) is bad practise

Comment: Check your network tab in your developer tools to see whats different across browsers.

Comment: QKarthik Ganesan, I didn't use a ~success:` callback because I don't return data only post it, just for good practice I'll add it back and capture any return text just so when it is hit, I'll see it there too.  There was one there I removed, it never got hit, nor does the failure callback.  @Musa, I don't see a `network tab` in Visual Studios 2013, but your correct in thinking something is difference 'cuz it does work in the IDE but not when deployed to the server.  I was thinking headers, but I can find no evidence of that.

Comment: Added the `success:` code to the script, even added an `alert` so I could see it get hit.  Nothing in Internet Explorer, got an alert in both Firefox and Chrome, says response is undefined, but I know it hit!  Every day I become less and less of a fan of IE, don't even ask me about Windows 10 and edge!  Oh, Karthik Ganesan, I took out the async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  I changed the code, wrapped it with a function call and added a try catch to make it easier to debug.  My code:

```
    function postdata(DTO) {
        var success = false;
        try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "Plan.aspx/SaveData",
                data: JSON.stringify(DTO), 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                traditional: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    success = true;
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Ajax post failed, the error is: " + response.responseText)//+ " Test = " + test);

                    success = false;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Error) {
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

The catch traps the error `JSON is undefined`, and here I thought it was native to the browser, well not with IE, I had to add a javascript file called json3.js, you can find it here:

https://bestiejs.github.io/json3/

Now it works in ALL three browsers ... now if I can just get Edge to work ... that's another story ... don't know why I didn't use try catch before, could have saved me some time.